# Clarification on how =countif(A:A,A1)>0 works as a conditional formatting rule

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

Everything I've read says that the countif function works as =countif(range, criteria).  It seems to work that way in the sheet itself, but I'm confused about how it works as as a custom formula in Conditional formatting.

I enter =countif(A:A, A1)>1 as a custom formula applied to Range A:A.

Assuming the following values are in column A:

5
10
23
54
6
65
10
65

The values 10 and 65 are highlighted, which is the outcome I want.  But since I specified A1 as the criteria (which contains a value of 5), shouldn't all fields not be highlighted since there's only 1 field with a value of 5?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`A1` in `=COUNTIF(A:A, A1)>1` is not locked like `A$1` so it iterates over the whole specified range. in other words it runs:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A, A1)>1
```

and then it continues like:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A, A1)>1
=COUNTIF(A:A, A2)>1
=COUNTIF(A:A, A3)>1
...
```

its an advantage of custom formulae that they can iterate ower the range

Comment: thank you!  that's very helpful.

however, i've been playing around with the formula and if i change A1 to something like A8, it starts to highlight seemingly random cells.  any ideas on why that is?

https://imgur.com/WHfZmTK

Comment: @enterprised1 because you're using `A8` in a formula applied to `A1:...`, it highlights cells based on whether *the cell 7 rows further down* is a duplicate.

Comment: that's what i assumed as well, but in the screenshot, 3, 6, and 32 are highlighted and none of those have duplicates...

Comment: @enterprised1 improper use of the formula will always result in nonsense undesired results. if you want to use A8 then you should apply it to A8:A range

Comment: @enterprised1 3, 6, and 32 are highlighted, and none of those have duplicates, but the cells *7 rows down* from them contain 5, 10, and 45.

Answer (score 0):

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,A1)>1
```

this formula does not works on some sheets
then try this:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A;A1)>1
```

https://screenrec.com/share/8qXCKzxHtc